# How to write RSA encrypt function in C#

Tags: c#, node.js, rsa

I have following nodejs code to encrypt RSA:

```
const encryptWithRSA = (PublicKey, selData) => {
    let encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(
        {
            key: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${PublicKey}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----,
            padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
        },
        Buffer.from(selData)
    );
    return encrypted.toString("base64");
};
```

Then I tried to convert this code block to C# :

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
public static string Encrypt(string publickey, string data)
{

    string key = publickey;

    Asn1Object obj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(Convert.FromBase64String(key));

    DerSequence publicKeySequence = (DerSequence)obj;

    DerBitString encodedPublicKey = (DerBitString)publicKeySequence[1];
    DerSequence publicKey = (DerSequence)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(encodedPublicKey.GetBytes());

    DerInteger modulus = (DerInteger)publicKey[0];
    DerInteger exponent = (DerInteger)publicKey[1];

    RsaKeyParameters keyParameters = new RsaKeyParameters(false, modulus.PositiveValue, exponent.PositiveValue);
    RSAParameters parameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(keyParameters);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);

    byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
}
```

Two code return 2 different results. Anyone can show me what wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with things such as `DerBitString`. Are they provided by a third party library, or something you've created?

Comment: Why using third party libraries when its inbuilt in .net System.Security.Cryptography

Comment: The key used in the NodeJS code is a public RSA key in X.509/SPKI format, PEM encoded. PKCS#1 v1.5 is used as padding, _each encryption returns a different result by definition (!)_, i.e. the different results you noticed do not indicate a bug. A reliable test would be the decryption with the corresponding private key. However, there are more efficient ways for the key import, depending on the .NET variant (Core / Framework) and version, neither of which you posted. E.g. as of . NET Core 3.0 no _BouncyCastle_ is required.

Comment: @Sunil I looked for some, but not found yet.

Comment: @Topaco I'm using .NET Framework 4.6. Do you have any suggestion for that version?